# Increment operation in 24 bit counter

Tags: verilog, counter

This is a 24 bit counter verilog program. What is the function of highlighted operation? Do we add 1 to the least significant bit? How can we know that the addition was done to the least significant bit if we consider `24'b1`.

[image]

I'm confused because of the usage of `24'b1`

doesn't that code mean we add 1 to all bits?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Verilog tutorial will answer your question.

```
<width>'<base><value>
```

So `24'b1` means:

```
<24 bit wide>'<binary><value of 1>
```

So it has the value of 1.

---

Now it can get a little more complex if you don't declare the constant as the correct width. If you use a constant of width 1bit and value 1 in a 24bit signed calculation, then the constant would actually be sign extended as -1, not 1. To address the other answer, this is why you should always declare your constant widths.

But in your case you are using unsigned registers, so this won't be an issue. You have also done the correct thing and declared the constant to be the correct width to match the calculation, so the value used will always be the same as what you specify in the constant.

---

There is one special case for the constants:

```
'1
```

In this case neither a base, nor a width was specified. This means, create a constant where all bits should be a 1 that matches the width of the calculation. You can do the same with all zeros (`'0`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do increment in code,

```
counter <= counter + 1'b1; // It is okay with all, lint and synthesis cleaned line, you can use 1'd1 instead of 1'b1 

counter <= counter + 1;  // take 1 as 32-bit integer decimal so flag synthesis warning that it produce 32-bit result 

counter <= counter + 24'b1;  // It can be used
```

And yes, It only adds one in  counter's previous value.